# inputMismatchException Java reading doubles from plain text file

Tags: java

Using

```
 double variable = inputFile.nextDouble();
```

Gives the mismatch error and I can't figure out why...  Anyone know what's up?

The input file is just a bunch of doubles like 5.0...

Okay here is the code snippet

```
String fileName;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("\nEnter file name that contains the matrix and vector: ");
fileName = scanner.nextLine();
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fileName);


double a1 = inputFile.nextDouble();
```

the input file is a plain text document .txt in this format

```
5.0 4.0 -3.0
4.0 2.0  5.0
6.0 5.0 -2.0
-13.0 4.0 12.0
```

I don't understand why it wouldn't take those as doubles...

As far as what its expecting the format of the file to be... I suppose binary?  isn't that the default?  I didn't specify in the code...

Comment: Please, post this error.

Comment: Could we also see how you declare your `inputFile` object (I assume it's a `Scanner`?) as well as some samples from the file itself?

Comment: What type is input file? Is it expecting binary or text encoding?

Comment: You have the wrong constructor for file `Scanner`. See my update below. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a check beforehand

```
if (inputFile.hasNextDouble()) { 
 double variable = inputFile.nextDouble();
} else if (inputFile.hasNext()) {
 System.out.println("Not double at token " + inputFile.next());
}
```

in order to identify why and where exactly it fails.

It could be that your delimiter isn't `" "` and that you haven't specified it manually. 
To set the delimiter, call one of `useDelimiter(...)` functions.

---

Answer (score 1):

`InputMismatchException` is the result of a scanner attempting to parse a string into a format to which it cannot to parsed.  For example, calling `Double.parseDouble` on a string such as "3.3 meters" will throw a NumberFormatException.  As *iccthedral* added, even a string as nontrivial as "3.0 " (notice the whitespace) will result in an NFE.

When a NumberFormatException occurs in `Scanner.nextDouble()`, the NFE is wrapped and rethrown in an InputMismatchException, which is what is occuring here.

To ensure that your Scanner *can* read a double, call `Scanner#hasNextDouble()` and only proceed to acquire the double *if* the scanner has that next double.

Comment: @iccthedral Correct. Think I should add it in to the answer as another example?